# What does `tar cvf fred|flintstone <barney&rubble> betty` do in a Perl system command?

Tags: perl

What does the below statement say exactly?

```
my @dirs = qw(fred|flintstone <barney&rubble> betty );
```

The complete story is:

```
my $tarfile = "something*wicked.tar";
my @dirs = qw(fred|flintstone <barney&rubble> betty );
system "tar", "cvf", $tarfile, @dirs;
```

This has been taken from *Learning Perl*, 4th Edition.

The result that the `system command`  will run on shell is:

```
tar cvf fred|flintstone <barney&rubble> betty
```

But does this command has a meaning on unix?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Perl provides a lot of help directly on the command line: `perldoc -f qw`, which leads to `perldoc perlop`, which contains a good explanation.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what that command does. We used it as an example only to show that you can do complicated shell things through system. You can completely ignore the particular shell command and not lose anything in the bits of Perl we are explaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qw()` splits the string between parentheses through whitespaces (spaces, tabs, any number of them) and returns a list: `"fred|flintstone", "<barney&rubble>", "betty"`

**EDIT**: hint from @kemp: it returns a list

And now to your updated question:

```
tar cvf fred|flintstone <barney&rubble> betty
```

Yes, the characters `|`, `<`, `>` and `&` do have meanings in Linux:

`|` redirects the standard output from `tar cvf fred` to the standard input of `flintstone`.

`<` sends the file `barney` to the standard input of `flintstone`

`&` runs the previous command and sends it to background

`>` writes the standard output of `rubble`  to the file `betty`

Whether the whole line has a meaning, it depends on individual programs.

Comment: Technically `qw` creates a list, not an array

Comment: well,evryone here is correct but i choose the one with least points.so others ..please dont mind

Comment: In this case the special characters have no meaning on the command line, the code is using the LIST form of `system` resulting in a command like `"tar" "cvf" "fred|flintstone" "<barney&rubble>" "betty"` That is run tar, verbosely create a tarball name "fred|flintstone" with the files/directories "<barney&rubble>" and "betty".

Answer (score 5):

From [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators):

```
qw/STRING/
           Evaluates to a list of the words extracted out of STRING, using
           embedded whitespace as the word delimiters.  It can be understood
           as being roughly equivalent to:

               split(' ', q/STRING/);

           the differences being that it generates a real list at compile
           time, and in scalar context it returns the last element in the
           list.  So this expression:

               qw(foo bar baz)

           is semantically equivalent to the list:

               'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
```

Answer (score 3):

It creates a list of the following values:

```
fred|flinstone
<barney&rubble>
betty
```

and assigns it to the array `@dirs`.

`qw` stands for "quote words" so it creates a list of the values given using a white space as separator.

Regarding your edit: the unix command `tar` creates an archive of the given files.
`cvf` are flags to control its behavior:

```
c - create archive
v - verbose mode
f - use following argument as archive name
```

next comes the name of the file you want to save the archive to, and a list of other files to be included in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Data::Dumper to look what dirs looks like:

```
$ perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; my @dirs = qw(fred|flintstone <barney&rubble> betty ); print Dumper(@dirs);'

$VAR1 = 'fred|flintstone';
$VAR2 = '<barney&rubble>';
$VAR3 = 'betty';
```

Or thanks to Eugene:

```
$ perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; my @dirs = qw(fred|flintstone <barney&rubble> betty ); print Dumper \@dirs;'
$VAR1 = [
          'fred|flintstone',
          '<barney&rubble>',
          'betty'
        ];
```

which is even better!

[Quote_and_Quote_like_Operators](http://www.sdsc.edu/~moreland/courses/IntroPerl/docs/manual/pod/perlop.html#Quote_and_Quote_like_Operators) is helpful too. It reminds qq qw and so.

Comment: Dumping a reference can be more descriptive: `print Dumper \@dirs;`